# Unable to find wifi connection with Ubuntu - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I recently purchased a used Samsung Galaxy Book and after experiencing Win 10 I dual booted with Ubuntu 20.04.

I have been researching the forums but I am still unable to make the wifi work or even find any signals.

As a last resort I have also installed Connman hoping it would find the connection but no luck.

Although I do not understand the technicalities I suspect the problem is something to do with firmware & backports!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Galaxy-Book-12:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

 *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:df400000-df5fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:4.2.2
       logical name: enx00909e9dd80e
       serial: 00:90:9e:9d:d8:0e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a duplex=full ip=192.168.1.64 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s

ubuntu@ubuntu-Galaxy-Book-12:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
ubuntu@ubuntu-Galaxy-Book-12:~$ ip link set wlan0 up
Cannot find device "wlan0"
ubuntu@ubuntu-Galaxy-Book-12:~$ iwconfig
enx00909e9dd80e  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Galaxy-Book-12:~$ dmesg | grep ath10k_pci. 
[    3.953267] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.958939] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    4.240389] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 144d:c14f
[    4.240392] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.240859] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    4.313310] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[    4.413664] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    4.538700] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.636512] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to initialise regulatory: -22
[    4.636515] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: could not register to mac80211 (-22)
```

Comment: you can see `driver=ath10k_pci` in configuration line of the wireless network adapter so please provide `dmesg | grep ath10k_pci`.

Comment: @binarysta the OP has added the requested information.